Do we always have $|\mathrm{Mor}_K(K(\alpha),F)|$ divide $|\mathrm{Mor}_K(K(\alpha),\overline{K})|$ with $\alpha\in F$ algebraic over $K$?
Let $F/K$ be an algebraic field extension and $\alpha\in F$. Let $m(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$.
Then $|\mathrm{Mor}_K(K(\alpha),F)|$ is the size of the roots of $m(x)$ in $F$ and $|\mathrm{Mor}_K(K(\alpha),\overline{K})|$ is the size of the roots of $m(x)$ in $\overline{K}$ (not counting multiplicity).
It's fairly easy to see that $|\mathrm{Mor}_K(K(\alpha),F)|$ is always a multiple of $|\mathrm{Mor}_K(K(\alpha),K(\alpha))|$, in particular,  $|\mathrm{Mor}_K(K(\alpha),K(\alpha))|$ divides $|\mathrm{Mor}_K(K(\alpha),\overline{K})|$. But do we always have $|\mathrm{Mor}_K(K(\alpha),F)|$ divides $|\mathrm{Mor}_K(K(\alpha),\overline{K})|$?
Update: To see that $|\mathrm{Mor}_K(K(\alpha),F)|$ is always a multiple of $|\mathrm{Mor}_K(K(\alpha),K(\alpha))|$, consider the set of $\alpha$-conjugates in $K(\alpha)$, say $M=\{\alpha_1=\alpha,\cdots,\alpha_m\}$ and the set of  $\alpha$-conjugates in $F$, say $N=\{\alpha_1=\alpha,\cdots,\alpha_n\}$. We define a relation on $N$ by $\alpha_i \sim \alpha_j$ if there exists $\sigma\in \mathrm{Mor}(K(\alpha),F)$ s.t. $\alpha_i,\alpha_j\in \sigma(M)$.
Clearly this is reflexive and symmetric. If $\alpha_i,\alpha_j\in \sigma(M)$ and $\alpha_j,\alpha_k\in \tau(M)$, by considering precomposing with $\sigma^{-1}:=\sigma^{-1}|_{\sigma(K(\alpha))}$ and suitable renaming, we may assume $\sigma=\mathrm{id}_{K(\alpha)}$, so $\alpha_j\in M$ and thus $\alpha_j\in \tau(K(\alpha_1))=\tau(K(\alpha_j))$. Hence $K(\alpha_j)\subset \tau(K(\alpha_j))$ and they are equal considering dimensions, thus $\tau\in \mathrm{Mor}_K(K(\alpha),K(\alpha))$ and $\alpha_k\in N$. Hence transitivity of $\sim$. It follows that $m|n$.

How are you getting that $|\operatorname{Mor}_K(K(\alpha),F)|$ is a multiple of $|\operatorname{Mor}_K(K(\alpha),K(\alpha))|$?

@AlexMathers See the update for the proof.

@user297024 say $F$ is generatd by $d$ roots of $m(x)$, but the resulting $F$ could contain more than $d$ roots. How can you be sure that there exists exactly $d$ roots in $F$?

@user297024 nevermind, I see the point of the splitting field with Galois group $S_n$ now.
